# mongoDB weird results after mathematical operations

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, e-commerce, addition

I have an e-commerce site with digital products (no inventory, only reporting features).

And sometimes i get weird results with customers account balances:

e.g. customer has 30 on his balance and after purchasing a product for 29.95 i see in admin panel that his balance is `0.050000000000001` not `0.05` as expected.

Or sometimes i see `520.949999999999` instead of `520.95`.

Why is this happening?

Site runs on PHP and interacts with mongo though [YiiMongoDbSuite](https://github.com/canni/YiiMongoDbSuite)

Comment: Could it be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: No, if he is not using JS to insert then that is not related, are you formatting the numbers before resaving them? If not then that is actually the reason; you need to tell PHP how you wanna save them

Comment: I was confusing yii with yui.

Comment: @Sammaye I just do something like `$userCollection->balance -= 29.95; $userCollection->save()`. Which should pretty much do the trick. But it doesn't.

Comment: yea that won't, PHP can change the precision to what it wants, use `number_format`

Answer (score 0):

Using double or floats is not advisable for any sort of currency math where precise calculations are vital. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) goes into great detail on the subject. A better alternative would be to track these values with integers, where `1` is the smallest unit of currency (cent in this case), and work from there.

Depending on how you do the math on floating points (saving exact values, the result of subtraction, or using the [`$inc`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/inc/) operator), you're likely to end up with mixed results:

```
> db.foo.insert({ _id: 'value', x: 0.05 })
> db.foo.insert({ _id: 'subtraction', x: 30 - 29.95 })
> db.foo.insert({ _id: 'decrement',  x: 30 })
> db.foo.update({ _id: 'decrement' }, { $inc: { x: -29.95 }})
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : "value", "x" : 0.05 }
{ "_id" : "subtraction", "x" : 0.05000000000000071 }
{ "_id" : "decrement", "x" : 0.05000000000000071 }
```

If you're set on using floating points and doing the math in PHP (i.e. not using `$inc` in the update query), consider using [round()](http://php.net/round) with a set precision, which should yield results similar to the first example above. number_format() is fine for display, but be careful not to use it when updating the document, since it returns a string.